# Loop over lines of a file

Tags: bash, shell, script

Here is my script:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

for line in $(cat list);
do
    echo "[$line]: Getting my workers list..";
    var=$line-"worker1";
    echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
    var=$line-"worker2";
    echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
    var=$line-"worker3";
    echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
done
fi
```

How can I change the treatment of the first line of the file? As this:

```sh
If(it is the first line)
  echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
  var=$line-"worker2";
  echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
  var=$line-"worker3";
Else 
  echo "[$line]: Getting my workers list..";
  var=$line-"worker1";
  echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
  var=$line-"worker2";
  echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
  var=$line-"worker3";
  echo "$var" >> "hostlistworkers.txt"
```

Comment: This should really be asked within Stack Overflow, that is where all programming related posts are.  Also, you need to explain what you have tried already and whether this has or hasn't worked and any error messages you have received.

Comment: you should state the scripting language e.g. bash in the title and in tag, if it's bash.. Note that sh isn't always bash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash   though i'd take a bit of a guess and say it is in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare a flag:

```
FIRST=0

if [ ! $FIRST ]; then
  ; do what you need
  FIRST=1
else
  ...
fi
```